# Google Analytics : Unique Purchases is not reflecting

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am referring to this site https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ua/gtm/enhanced-ecommerce to send e-commerce data from the Google tag manager to the Google analytics dashboard.

Below is the GTM tag for the order-receipt page. While other checkout operations are kept in separate tags.
I am trying to send the purchase event through custom HTML in GTM Tag:

```html
<script>
  ga('create', 'UA-random-id-12', 'auto', {'name': 'PurchasePage'});
  ga('PurchasePage.require', 'ec');

  ga('PurchasePage.set', 'dimension1', 'c4f0cab13b5537uid32yiu334f0354c18');

  ga('PurchasePage.ec:addProduct', {
    'id': '12345',
    'name': 'App1',
    'price': '10.0000000000',
    'variant': '7364284628',
    'quantity': 1,
    'coupon': '',
    'brand': 'EYUIYEI',
    'currency': 'USD'
  });

  ga('PurchasePage.set', 'dimension2', 'ALL');

  ga('PurchasePage.set', 'dimension3', 'Marketplace');

  ga('PurchasePage.set', 'dimension4', true);

  ga('PurchasePage.ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
    'id': '12345', 'revenue': '110.0000000000', 'tax': '0.0000000000', 'coupon': null, 'step': 4,
  });

  ga('PurchasePage.ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
    'step': 4
  });

  ga('PurchasePage.send', 'pageview', {
    'title': 'Order Receipt Page'
  });
</script>
```

I can see the debug logs on the chrome console where the purchase event is being sent

```js
                         _                          _       _   _
                        | |                        | |     | | (_)
  __ _  ___   ___   __ _| | ___    __ _ _ __   __ _| |_   _| |_ _  ___ ___
 / _` |/ _ \ / _ \ / _` | |/ _ \  / _` | '_ \ / _` | | | | | __| |/ __/ __|
| (_| | (_) | (_) | (_| | |  __/ | (_| | | | | (_| | | |_| | |_| | (__\__ \
 \__, |\___/ \___/ \__, |_|\___|  \__,_|_| |_|\__,_|_|\__, |\__|_|\___|___/
  __/ |             __/ |                              __/ |
 |___/             |___/                              |___/

react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Running analytics_debug.js. This script is intended for testing and debugging only.
...
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.require", "ec")
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Executing Google Analytics commands.
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.require", "ec")
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Executing Google Analytics commands.
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "ec", Function)
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.require", "ec")
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Plugin "ec" intialized on tracker "PurchasePage".
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.set", "dimension1", "c4f0cab13b5537uid32yiu334f0354c18")
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.ec:addProduct", {id: "310647", name: "App1", price: "10.0000000000", variant: "7364284628", quantity: 1, coupon: "", brand: "EYUIYEI", currency: "USD"})
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.set", "dimension2", "ALL")
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.set", "dimension3", "MP")
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.set", "dimension4", true)
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.ec:setAction", "purchase", {id: "6332d33fe8d5156c6bb6b68b", revenue: "110.0000000000", tax: "0.0000000000", coupon: null, step: 4})
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.ec:setAction", "checkout", {step: 4})
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Running command: ga("PurchasePage.send", "pageview", {title: "Order Receipt Page"})
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Tag Assistant debug signal detected for unsupported legacy tag.
...
VM1232 analytics.js:30 Setting throttling cookie: "_gat_OrderReceiptPage"
VM1232 analytics.js:30
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j97d&a=2039992036&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Ftestqwerty.qaz.com%2Freceipt%2F001965%3ForderUuid%3D12345%26gtm_debug%3D123&dr=https%3A%2F%2Ftagassistant.google.com%2F&ul=en-gb&de=UTF-8&dt=Order%20Receipt%20Page&sd=30-bit&sr=1792x1120&vp=1792x373&je=0&_u=yCCAAUIJAAAAAC~&jid=1383585562&gjid=1942449811&cid=296136795.1634033045&tid=UA-randomid-8&_gid=376555535.1664271026&_r=1&cd1=c4f0cab13b5537uid32yiu334f0354c18&cd2=ALL&cd3=MP&cd4=1&cos=4&pa=checkout&pr1id=12345&pr1nm=App1&pr1pr=10.0000000000&pr1va=7364284628&pr1qt=1&pr1cc=&pr1br=EYUIYEI&z=136380644


VM1232 analytics.js:30 _j1                     (&jid)   1383585562
VM1232 analytics.js:30 _j2                     (&gjid)  1942449811
VM1232 analytics.js:30 adSenseId               (&a)     2039992036
VM1232 analytics.js:30 apiVersion              (&v)     1
VM1232 analytics.js:30 clientId                (&cid)   296136795.1634033045
VM1232 analytics.js:30 dimension1              (&cd1)   c4f0cab13b5537uid32yiu334f0354c18
VM1232 analytics.js:30 dimension2              (&cd2)   ALL
VM1232 analytics.js:30 dimension3              (&cd3)   MP
VM1232 analytics.js:30 dimension4              (&cd4)   1
VM1232 analytics.js:30 ec:action               (&pa)    checkout
VM1232 analytics.js:30 ec:product "1" brand    (&pr1br) EYUIYEI
VM1232 analytics.js:30 ec:product "1" coupon   (&pr1cc)
VM1232 analytics.js:30 ec:product "1" id       (&pr1id) 310647
VM1232 analytics.js:30 ec:product "1" name     (&pr1nm) App1
VM1232 analytics.js:30 ec:product "1" price    (&pr1pr) 10.0000000000
VM1232 analytics.js:30 ec:product "1" quantity (&pr1qt) 1
VM1232 analytics.js:30 ec:product "1" variant  (&pr1va) 7364284628
VM1232 analytics.js:30 ec:step                 (&cos)   4
VM1232 analytics.js:30 encoding                (&de)    UTF-8
VM1232 analytics.js:30 hitType                 (&t)     pageview
VM1232 analytics.js:30 javaEnabled             (&je)    0
VM1232 analytics.js:30 language                (&ul)    en-gb
VM1232 analytics.js:30 location                (&dl)    https://testqwerty.qaz.com/receipt/001965?orderUuid=12345&gtm_debug=123
VM1232 analytics.js:30 referrer                (&dr)    https://tagassistant.google.com/
VM1232 analytics.js:30 screenColors            (&sd)    30-bit
VM1232 analytics.js:30 screenResolution        (&sr)    1792x1120
VM1232 analytics.js:30 title                   (&dt)    Order Receipt Page
VM1232 analytics.js:30 trackingId              (&tid)   UA-randomid-8
VM1232 analytics.js:30 viewportSize            (&vp)    1792x373
```

But on GA dashboard, the unique events are showing as blank.

[image: GA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the `PurchasePage.ec:setAction', 'checkout'` from the script, I was able to see unique events on the analytics dashboard.

```html
<script>
  ga('create', 'UA-random-id-12', 'auto', {'name': 'PurchasePage'});
  ga('PurchasePage.require', 'ec');

  ga('PurchasePage.set', 'dimension1', 'c4f0cab13b5537uid32yiu334f0354c18');

  ga('PurchasePage.ec:addProduct', {
    'id': '12345',
    'name': 'App1',
    'price': '10.0000000000',
    'variant': '7364284628',
    'quantity': 1,
    'coupon': '',
    'brand': 'EYUIYEI',
    'currency': 'USD'
  });

  ga('PurchasePage.set', 'dimension2', 'ALL');

  ga('PurchasePage.set', 'dimension3', 'Marketplace');

  ga('PurchasePage.set', 'dimension4', true);

  ga('PurchasePage.ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
    'id': '12345', 'revenue': '110.0000000000', 'tax': '0.0000000000', 'coupon': null, 'step': 4,
  });

  ga('PurchasePage.send', 'pageview', {
    'title': 'Order Receipt Page'
  });
</script>
```